# when is the speech recognition in iOS restricted i.e requestAuthorization returns `SFSpeechRecognizerAuthorizationStatusRestricted`

Tags: ios, objective-c, speech-recognition

I'm making an app which will be using Speech Recognition and want to know how frequently or when will my app encounter this scenario

I know that this related to device restricting Speech recognition rather than user but when exactly ??
is it due to some specific models not supporting speech recognition or is iOS version specific
or are there some settings that can restrict apps from using Speech recognition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though no longer quite accurate, think of a restriction as a parental control that blocks a user from even having the option to enable a service controlled by device privacy settings.

https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201304

This falls under **"Here are the things you can restrict:"**

> Speech Recognition: Prevent apps from accessing Speech Recognition or
>   Dictation

How often will you encounter it? Who knows, but if your app targets minors, then that is likely an increased chance, but this is purely speculative.

To answer your other question:

> ...is it due to some specific models not supporting speech
>   recognition...

There is a different way to test for speech support on a device:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizer/1649885-isavailable

Using `isAvailable` (for Swift) or `available` (Obj-C), you can tell if the speech recognizer is available.

Since you marked your question as Objective-C, then the following would work:

```
SFSpeechRecognizer *recognizer = [[SFSpeechRecognizer alloc] init];
if (recognizer.available) {
    // Do recognizer things
}
```

The same in Swift:

```
let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
if recognizer.isAvailable { }
```